# Connect to MongoDB Docker Container from Compass

Tags: mongodb, docker, compass

I am unable to use Compass (v1.30.1) to connect to a Docker container running an instance of mongodb

I have a very simple docker container with mongodb on Windows10.
`docker run --name mongoTest -d -p 27017:27018 mongo`

Using Compass (v1.30.1) and the following connection string
`mongodb://localhost:27017`

I receive the following error from Compass:
`connection <monitor> to 127.0.0.1:27017 closed`

Any help appreciated to get this working and an explanation.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `docker run --name mongoTest -d -p 27018:27017 mongo` and connect to `mongodb://localhost:27018`